# Numbers, letters and words on top of guitar music score notes

Tags: guitar, notation, classical-music

I'm trying to play 'Gran Vals' by Tarrega, and the music score has several letters accompanied by a number on top of the notes, for example:

***C.2a_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ __ _***

In some cases there are words like

***ten:***

Here is the score:

[image: Score]

**What does this mean?**

Can any one provide a link where I can review this type of notation?

Answer (score 8):

These expressions are common in classical guitar music.

`ten:` means *tenuto*, which is a playing style used for effect. Each note should be held for its full length. Do not confuse this with *legato, tenuto* is holding notes for their full length but not necessarily playing them smoothly or softly.

The `C.2a` Is a barre. This is unique to stringed instruments and it is when you lay one finger (usually the first finger) across all or some of the strings on one fret. A full barre is across all six strings, while a half barre is across the top three or so strings (sometimes four). The number shows you which fret this is done on. the `------¬` written after this shows you how long to hold the barre for in the music, and you should lift your finger at the end of the line.

I have not seen a barre written in this form before, usually it is written as a capital 'C' followed by roman numerals for the fret and the same line indication. A half fraction before the 'C' (or a dash vertically through it) indicates a half barre:

[image]

Comment: Thank you!
It makes it easier to understand how to play this piece.
Is there a link you recommend where all of this notation is explained? The results that came up after I googled were somewhat confusing.
Thanks again!

Comment: this was from my own knowledge with reassurance from google, but i'll look for a site for you.

Comment: Try [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_musical_symbols) page for notation, and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_musical_terminology) page for expressions (use CTRL + F to search for the right term)

Comment: "A half fraction before the 'C' indicates a half barre" An alternative notation is a dashed C , eg https://musescore.org/sites/musescore.org/files/Example_3.jpg